# How can I mount partition disk0s4 that became inaccessible after a clean installation of Mountain Lion?

Tags: mac, macos, install, partition

The hard drive on my MacBook Pro has two partitions. One with the OS and the other with data.

Yesterday, from a USB boot drive, I performed a clean installation of Mountain Lion to the OS drive. I created the USB boot installer from InstallESD.dmg that I received from purchasing the OS from the Mac App Store.

Now I can't see or mount my data partition.  I'm wondering if there's a problem with the MBR. In Disk Utility it shows up as "disk0s4", but it's greyed out.

Any ideas on how I can mount the data partition so I can get my data off it?

For `diskutil list disk0` the result is:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                                 TYPE NAME         SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                GUID_partition_scheme             *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                                  EFI              209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                            Apple_HFS MacBook OS    99.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                           Apple_Boot Recovery HD  650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4: 46860E2C-2310-4F96-99F6-616D0B4CB55D              399.6 GB   disk0s4
```

Here's the result of `diskutil info /dev/disk0s4`

```
Device Identifier:        disk0s4
Device Node:              /dev/disk0s4
Part of Whole:            disk0
Device / Media Name:      MacBook Data

Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)

Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)

File System:              None

Partition Type:           46860E2C-2310-4F96-99F6-616D0B4CB55D
OS Can Be Installed:      No
Media Type:               Generic
Protocol:                 SATA
SMART Status:             Verified

Total Size:               399.6 GB (399629668352 Bytes) (exactly 780526696 512-Byte-Blocks)
Volume Free Space:        Not applicable (no file system)
Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

Read-Only Media:          No
Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)
Ejectable:                No

Whole:                    No
Internal:                 Yes
Solid State:              No
```

Comment: /dev/disk0
   0: GUID_partition_scheme  *500.1 GB   disk0
   1: EFI  209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2: Apple_HFS MacBook OS  99.5 GB    disk0s2
   3: Apple_Boot Recovery HD  650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4: 46860E2C-2310-4F96-99F6-616D0B4CB55D  399.6 GB   disk0s4

Comment: I installed from a USB boot disk I created.  Upgraded on several other machines with no issues.  I'm trying a demo of ProSoftEng's Data Rescue 3 now.  I just want to get my data!

Comment: Did you use `InstallESD.dmg` alone (without Install OS X Mountain Lion.app) to produce that USB boot disk? Please edit the opening question to include the information … and for the moment, set aside thoughts of other machines; let's focus on this one – thanks.

Comment: For at least one build of Lion: `Install.ESD` was **not** applicable to all Lion-capable Macs. [Wonder](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/59239/8546) whether the same is true for Mountain Lion.

Comment: The answer from @DeepanshuUtkarsh helped me to find other questions that may be of interest: [Best resources on data recovery from corrupted OS X HFS+ partitions](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/4326/8546) (2010-11-24), [Recover partitions or data after partition map becomes corrupted (HFS+)](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/13690/8546) (2011-05-07) and [How to recover a deleted/replaced HFS+ partition from external drive?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/52932/8546) (2012-06-05).

Answer (score 5):

## Mounting the volume

### Disk Utility verification and possible repair of the partition map

If you have not already done so, use Disk Utility 13 (426) in OS X 10.8 to select then verify:

- **not** the greyed-out partition
- instead, the physical disk that contains the partition.

If verification reveals a problem with the partition map, then consider allowing Disk Utility to attempt a repair.

### Proceeding without Disk Utility

[Credit to Caesium's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/59127/8546) for finding the `asr` suggestion.

Here with a disposable JHFS+ volume, an example of adjustments working as expected. Note the file system checks:

```
macbookpro08-centrim:~ gjp22$ diskutil unmount /dev/disk12s1
Volume sandpit on disk12s1 unmounted
macbookpro08-centrim:~ gjp22$ sudo asr adjust --target /dev/disk12s1 --settype "Apple_UFS"
Fsck /dev/disk12s1 ....10....20....30....40....50....60....70....80....90....100
Adjust completed successfully
macbookpro08-centrim:~ gjp22$ diskutil list disk12
/dev/disk12
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *256.9 MB   disk12
   1:                  Apple_UFS sandpit                 256.9 MB   disk12s1
macbookpro08-centrim:~ gjp22$ diskutil mount readOnly /dev/disk12s1
Volume on disk12s1 failed to mount
macbookpro08-centrim:~ gjp22$ sudo asr adjust --target /dev/disk12s1 --settype "Apple_HFS"
Fsck /dev/disk12s1 ....10....20....30....40....50....60....70....80....90....100
Adjust completed successfully
macbookpro08-centrim:~ gjp22$ diskutil mount readOnly /dev/disk12s1
Volume sandpit on /dev/disk12s1 mounted
macbookpro08-centrim:~ gjp22$
```

If the type of your own `/dev/disk0s4` can not be safely adjusted or (re)set to `Apple_HFS` then:

- the operating system may no longer work with the HFS Plus file system (or remnants thereof) that occupies, or occupied, the affected area of the physical disk; and
- you might doubt the integrity of the partition (start and end blocks, and so on).

Relevant lines from `/private/var/log/install.log` should reveal what, if anything, happened to `disk0s4` before, during or after installation of the OS to `disk0s2`. This logged information may become critical to regaining easy access to the data.

## Getting the data without mounting the volume

Good luck with your use of Data Rescue 3 – I have the app, but have never attempted to recover from any area of a disk where the partition type has been affected in this way.

---

## Observations

### Device/media name

This is sometimes, not always, a match for the volume name. Here for example:

```
macbookpro08-centrim:~ gjp22$ diskutil info disk0s2 | grep Name:
   Device / Media Name:      swap
   Volume Name:              swap
macbookpro08-centrim:~ gjp22$ diskutil info disk0s4 | grep Name:
   Device / Media Name:      Untitled
   Volume Name:              spare
```

For Todd K., presence of the device/media name –

> MacBook Data

– raises hope that start and end blocks etc. are good, that only the `type` of the partition is wrong.

### No [Recovery System](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718) 10.8 for OS X 10.8

*Recovery HD* implies Recovery OS 10.7.x.

In any case such as this, an installation that is incomplete (that is without the expected upgrade to the `Apple_Boot` slice) signals that a nonstandard method of installation – with only part of Apple's installer app – may have been used.

### Side note

*GUID Partition Table*, as it's described in Disk Utility, is the norm for this type of modern installation of OS X – not Master Boot Record.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, two Google results if you search for that GUID, *46860E2C-2310-4F96-99F6-616D0B4CB55D*.

One of them refers to a command that might set the partition type back to Apple_HFS (assuming it was that in the first place?), so might be worth a go?

```
sudo asr adjust --target /dev/disk0s4 --settype "Apple_HFS"
```

Source: http://help.bombich.com/discussions/questions/12878-unable-to-boot-from-local-disk-after-verify-step

[Edit: seems like my asr on Mountain Lion doesn't have an **adjust** argument to `asr`] :(

Comment: I tried the sudo command and received the following message: Volume adjustment failed: Unknown error: -123

Comment: The `adjust` verb of [asr](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/asr.8.html) seems to be undocumented by Apple, but understood elsewhere, for example justindelliott/[PartitionAndRestoreLionRecoveryHD](https://github.com/justindelliott/PartitionAndRestoreLionRecoveryHD). I can find no information about the unknown error code.

Answer (score 2):

Download [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) and refer to the embedded instructions. It is a very powerful piece of software, so use it carefully. It will rebuild disk0s4’s partition and then the filesystem. All your files will be back as it is. I recommend this because it is very user friendly and I saved 2000 bucks on data recovery because of testdisk.

Comment: I'm trying it now.  It's the first tool that's even recognized the missing partition.  I'll post the outcome.  Thanks!

Comment: Is it normal for the "quick search" to take a long time?

Comment: No. You probably entered deep search. Did you specify GPT/EFI as the partition table type?
You should have written the partition table when it recognised the missing partition. Check the Readme file.

Comment: The readme.txt file just refers me to the web resources.
After running the sudo option, I see the drive listed four times as: /dev/disk0, /dev/disk3, /dev/rdisk0 and /dev/rdisk3.  I can see the "MacBook Data" partition on /dev/rdisk0.  

It tells me that write access for this media is not avaiable.  Do I need to boot in a recovery mode and not in the OS?

Comment: Whenever I try to "write", I get an error. Ugh.

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot that! You have to boot from the Recovery HD or other recovery media.

Comment: I can boot from the Recovery HD, but how can I access testdisk within Recovery?  Do I need to use Terminal? Any tips on this?

Comment: You have to learn some basic Terminal for that. Navigating within directories and stuff. I can’t help you step by step as your disk and directory structure will be obviously different from mine. Also, you have to boot from an EXTERNAL Recovery HD. This (http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1433?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) article will help you create an external Recovery HD.

Comment: Did you get going? Please update your progress regularly.

Comment: A most promising answer (though I never needed to use TestDisk). For simplicity, I might recommend installing OS X (not Recovery OS alone) to the external drive; the resulting environment will be more familiar.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I had to rsync data out of the partition, delete and recreate and re-move data back again..