# Corrupt Mac filesystem partition

Tags: partition, filesystem, hfs

I'm having exactly the same issue in this question:

[How can I mount partition disk0s4 that became inaccessible after a clean installation of Mountain Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59118/how-can-i-mount-partition-disk0s4-that-became-inaccessible-after-a-clean-install/264595#264595)

Has anyone found a solution please?

Comment: This is the same link in the question.

The partition that I have has 'none' filesystem, and I need to change it to HFS. I tried fsck, fdisk, testdisk and others, none worked.

Comment: I'm aware it's the same link as in your question. You have added no further information at all, not even which of the myriad solutions there you tried & what precisely happened when you did; hence my close-vote.

Comment: Nothing in the discussion in this link worked for me. It does not seem it worked for the owner of the question either. What I'm asking now is: has anyone found anything other than what's on this webpage? Or: has anyone found a solution!

Comment: Then the way to raise attention would be to set a bounty, or post a **new** question [as stated in the delete reason on your answer on that question [high rep users can see deleted answers, btw]] - at least containing some detail that differentiates it from what is currently an exact duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. My account here is new. This happened just when I decided to move to ubuntu. I'll just forsake my data and format the drive. Thank you for your time.